# A live view of an external website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How do you get a div that is populated with a live screen image of an external website without using iFrames?  e.g. www.google.com

I want to produce a portfolio website, I have a number of sites that are regularly updated.  What I want to do is have javascript open on page load, I want it to find a specific external site (e.g. www.google.com) and then take a screenshot.  Then I want it to display the screenshot on my portfolio page.  Or show a live view of the website inside a div. I dont want to use iFrames as I feel it just looks out of place.  I don't need the JS to save the screenshot, just to display it.

Comment: cant with pure js, but you can use phantom js if you have a server.

Comment: iframes "look out of place"?  What is it about the iframe that seems out of place? You can style an iframe to eliminate the border, make it a block level element, or pretty much anything else you can do with a div.